# .net core System.DirectoryServices not available?

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, .net-core, directoryservices

I'm creating a project targetting dotnetcore 2.0.

According to the MSDN, System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory should be usable in .net core 2.0 but I get an error that it can't find DirectoryServices under System.

The method I need is GetComputerDomain()

Is their an alternative for .net core 2.0?

I'm looking for an alternative to

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory

var domain = Domain.GetComputerDomain();
```

??

WOuld like to be able to get the domain on windows and linux machines.

Comment: are you going to run on windows or are you hoping for mac/windows?

Comment: Hi, I'm hoping for Windows / linux...

Comment: i dont think theres a one size fit all for linux binding to active directory domains.

Comment: Mixing concerns: there are alternative LDAP clients for use in .NET Core, but you don't seem to want to use LDAP but get info about a joined domain which is more complex since it would mean reading windows/samba/… configuration and potentially `/etc/resolv.conf` for search domains in non-joined computers.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I need to verify username, password against AD. System.DirectoryServices is not working in Linux. And our hosting server is Linux based. Any solution you found for this?

Answer (score 3):

System.DirectoryServices is now available in .net core 2.1; however, it works fine in Windows, but not in Linux (throws PlatformNotSupportedException, not sure whether it's an expected behavior).

Comment: What can be used to verify username, password in Active Diretory in .NET Core? I am facing same issue. System.DirectoryServices is not working in Linux. And our hosting server is Linux based.

Comment: @priya This works in Linux https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

Comment: Will it allow me to verify username, password pair for given domain name? Both in Windows and Linux?

Comment: Yes! check out the sample usage mentioned on the page referred above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer **System.DirectoryServices** manually in your project.
Here is the MSDN link about [managing references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) .

Comment: Sorry, got distracted. I got this working, It wouldn't let me add  reference to it in a dotnet core project. I had to install the nuget package Windows Compatibility Pack. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility but I'm not sure this will work for resolving domains in linux.

Comment: Did it worked? I am facing same issue. System.DirectoryServices is not working in Linux. And our hosting server is Linux based.